# how to debug maven tycho plugin?

Tags: tycho

I followed steps mentioned in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Developing_Tycho and downloaded tycho source code. 
To debug eclipse project (which uses maven tycho), I followed steps steps mentioned in
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dealing+with+Eclipse-based+IDE

Now when I run maven build and start remote debug application, it gives error as:

`Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.Connection refused: connect`

how can I get eclipse-maven port number?

Is there any other approach to debug tycho?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved! execute mvnDebug command from command line so it will halt at breakpoint and then start eclipse remote debug application. It works.. 
Previously I executed maven debug command from eclipse maven debug configuration which doesnt work.